# volume group not found after update with full encrypted disk - then boots anyway

Tags: encryption, lvm, luks, cryptsetup, aptdaemon

Since some November update of my 20.04.1 Ubuntu , during startup I get the messages `volume group "name" not found`. I get the password prompt and can log in but some system settings (sound setting, battery status, etc.) won't work. The system is not encrypted with the standard procedure but rather something along this [ManualFullSystemEncryption][1], allowing for custom partitioning - but with unencrypted `/boot` and `/boot/efi`.

startup messages:

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done. 
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... 
Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ...
  Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
  Cannot process volume group vgubuntu 
Please unlock disk lukslvm:
```

Initially, the system halted at the vendor splash screen and I had to reboot via ctrl-alt-del, so I would get to the grub menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, short after a GRUB update an aptdeamon process installed 32 bit versions of some packages, namely `systemd` and `plymouth` among others. The `plymouth i386` package crashed plymouth and made the previously hidden `volume group not found` error visible and the `systemd i386` package crashed system settings.

So the solution was to check for installed i386 packages with `dpkg` and remove them:

```bash
sudo apt install systemd:amd64 systemd-timesyncd:amd64 plymouth:amd64
dpkg -l | grep i386 # check
sudo apt purge $(dpkg --get-selections | awk '$1 ~ /:i386$/ { print $1 }')
dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Solutions from

[systemd: User daemons fail to start after after update removed snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290430/systemd-user-daemons-fail-to-start-after-after-update-removed-snap)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptdaemon/+bug/1903273

[How to remove all i386 packages from Ubuntu 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit)

The "*volume group not found*" error persists and stems from the `initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2` script, when it calls

```bash
lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster vgubuntu/root
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your question has gone unsolved for some time, did you try this solution? [The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189835/the-initramfs-will-attempt-to-resume-from-dev-dm-1/1191018#1191018)

For me, i was getting the exact error message you are getting but it showed twice (ie. "Volume not found" and "Cannot process" appeared in 2 pairs).

Keep in mind, because the volume is encrypted there will always be 1 pair of "*volume not found*" at boot start just before asking for a password.  That is by design -- done on purpose.  It tries to access the volume but because its encrypted it triggers a warning that it cant be found, yet, and then asks for the password before retrying again.

The above solution (link) helped because i had 2 pairs.  It dropped it down to 1 pair.  Remember, my disk is also encrypted so that 1 pair remaining is normal.

You mentioned this pair is caused by a line from `initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2`:

> lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster vgubuntu/root

That is true!  So, adding *`2>/dev/null`* to the end of that line will suppress that annoying message since the "*volume not found*" message does not mean there is a problem in our cases (ie. encrypted volume), so i might as well hide the unsightly display on boot.

Comment: Most of this seems reasonable until you hide the message.  Suppressing this one error message might be good, but do you really want to suppress all error messages that could ever come from that command?

Comment: Thanks, for me the `i386` packages the root cause of my problem, especially the `systemd` package. Due to the plymouth crash, the previously hidden message surfaced and led me on the complete wrong track, so I left it here for reference