# After latest software update 'Daemon for power management' fails to start

Tags: boot, grub2, power-management, aptdaemon

After installing and restarting my computer from the Ubuntu Software Updater prompt, my computer never completes a boot due to `Failed to start Daemon for power management` error:

```
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 789912/30498816 files, 66894142/121965056 blocks
^[[20~^[[20~^[[20~^[[20~^[[20~^[[20~^[[20~^[[20~[FAILED] Failed to start Daemon for power management.
See 'systemctl status upower.service' for details.
```

I tried to go into the GRUB and boot an older Linux version there, but the same issue occurred.

Being unable to boot my system, I went into Recovery Menu to attempt to solve issue from there. When I attempted to use `dpkg     Repair broken packages`, I hit another issue that I did not find talked about in the web:

```
Reading cache
Can not upgrade
An upgrade from 'bionic' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool."
```

As I keep running into issues popping up, I am not really sure what Ubuntu's Software Update really did to my computer. I am really not sure where to go at this point to address the issues.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Updated from what to what? Did you read the details in the file like the message told you to? systemctl status upower.service

Comment: Hello, I am currently unable to boot up the computer so I do not know how to access systemctl status upower.service. Likewise I was using the automated system updater that  ubuntu prompted me with. I believe it was updates to a ubuntu version 20.x

Comment: I would have to say re install from scratch with the version you want and forget about an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I was debating about whether that was the best course of action or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the log file /var/log/apt/history.log, check that whether `systemd:amd64` and `systemd-timesyncd:amd64` is removed, if they are you may be effected by
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptdaemon/+bug/1903273

Try installing them `sudo apt install systemd:amd64 systemd-timesyncd:amd64`

[systemd: User daemons fail to start after after update removed snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290430/systemd-user-daemons-fail-to-start-after-after-update-removed-snap)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In order to fix it I booted from GRUB and booted from an old version of the kernel. The steps are as follows:

1. During boot hit <kbd>F12</kbd> repeatedly in order to boot into BIOS. Do this from the moment you hit the power button until you see the logo for your computer's manufacturer.
2. From here in the BIOS, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> repeatedly and then press <kbd>Escape</kbd> and you'll enter the GRUB.
3. From here press `Advanced Settings` and select the 4.15 kernel and boot from it.

It should now work since 4.15 is the latest Ubuntu 18 kernel. If this doesn't work, try again in recovery.