# Ubuntu 20.04 lagging and behaving badly after I halted an update midway. Also, internet dongle & tethering are not detected

Tags: networking, 20.04, sound, updates, system-settings

In my Ubuntu Software Updater, I ticked some random updates that were available and clicked 'install'. But midway during the downloads I cancelled the update and powered off my system. Until before I powered off my system everything was working fine, and by that I mean: my internet and sound controls in system menu. Also there were no lags.

When I reopen my system, I see the following problems:

✔ System Menu Icons and System Menu Drop Down are all messed up.

[image]

✔ Some system menu icons (including the sound icon) are not visible.

✔ The system menu volume bar doesn't seem to have any effect on the volume. Although the speakers seem to be working, because they produce sound when I play some movie or mp3.

✔ When I open the system setting, it lags very badly and becomes unresponsive every now and then upon clicking.

✔ The sound settings inside system settings are all blank.

✖ Doesn't connect to internet when I insert my dongle. Also I am unable to connect via mobile tethering.

[image]

I have no idea how I should proceed to solve these problems, please help.

#### UPDATE 1

- I went ahead with the live boot chroot method as described in the link provided by raffa and then I did a full update+upgrade as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349675/1356558) by user535733. This did not fix any of the problems at first.
- I investigated my system services using `systemctl` and found that `user@1000.service` was failing to start. Then I looked up the problem and found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290430/systemd-user-daemons-fail-to-start-after-after-update-removed-snap). I used it along with the live boot method. This **fixed the lag in the system settings**.
- However, the sound settings are still blank, system menu is still messed up, and I can't connect to the internet by any means.
- Upon further investigation, I found that I have **a number of services marked as 'not-found'** in `systemctl`. I have listed them below. I highly suspect that these missing services are causing the problem.  Is there any way to fix these services?

```
$ systemctl --state=not-found

  UNIT                           LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION                   
● tmp.mount                      not-found inactive dead tmp.mount                     
● auditd.service                 not-found inactive dead auditd.service                
● connman.service                not-found inactive dead connman.service               
● console-screen.service         not-found inactive dead console-screen.service        
● firewalld.service              not-found inactive dead firewalld.service             
● kbd.service                    not-found inactive dead kbd.service                   
● oem-config.service             not-found inactive dead oem-config.service            
● plymouth-quit-wait.service     not-found inactive dead plymouth-quit-wait.service    
● plymouth-quit.service          not-found inactive dead plymouth-quit.service         
● plymouth-start.service         not-found inactive dead plymouth-start.service        
● slapd.service                  not-found inactive dead slapd.service                 
● sssd.service                   not-found inactive dead sssd.service                  
● systemd-update-done.service    not-found inactive dead systemd-update-done.service   
● systemd-vconsole-setup.service not-found inactive dead systemd-vconsole-setup.service
● ua-auto-attach.service         not-found inactive dead ua-auto-attach.service        
● xfs.service                    not-found inactive dead xfs.service                   
● all.target                     not-found inactive dead all.target                    
● display-manager.target         not-found inactive dead display-manager.target        
● x-display-manager.target       not-found inactive dead x-display-manager.target      

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

19 loaded units listed.
```

Request: I'd really like to fix this problem if possible because doing an OS reinstall is just not feasible for me right now. Any little guidance will be of great help.

#### UPDATE 2

- I did as instructed by @Raffa, and it worked!

> Most of the output in your `systemctl --state=not-found` is usual ... I would suggest reinstalling ubuntu-desktop like so `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

This **fixed the messed up system menu icons and drop-down and also the blank sound settings problem**.

- My internet dongle and tethering aren't connecting yet. There's seems to be some problem with `usb_modeswitch`.

```bsh
$ systemctl --failed
  UNIT                           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION           
● usb_modeswitch@2-1.5.4.service loaded failed failed USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.5.4
● vboxweb.service                loaded failed failed VirtualBox Web Service

$ systemctl status usb_modeswitch@2-1.5.4.service --no-pager
● usb_modeswitch@2-1.5.4.service - USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.5.4
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/usb_modeswitch@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-07-04 21:05:57 IST; 22min ago
       Docs: man:usb_modeswitch_dispatcher(1)
    Process: 1842 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher --switch-mode 2-1.5.4 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1842 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.5.4...
Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1842]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1842]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[1842]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@2-1.5.4.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@2-1.5.4.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 04 21:05:57 hcl-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.5.4.
```

I tried to fix it by a force reinstall, but to no avail.

Since doing a `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` fixed a lot of issues, I wonder if we can fix the rest by doing a reinstall of all the essential system applications and services. In which case, please tell me which services I should reinstall.

#### UPDATE 3

- Again, it turned out that the problem wasn't with `usb-modeswitch`, it's usual for it to show a 'failed' status even in normal conditions. I checked it in a live boot session where my dongle and tethering were working fine, yet
  `usb-modeswitch` showed a 'failed' error in `systemctl`. So, I think that's sufficient to rule out modeswitch as a culprit for the problem at hand.

##### New Findings

- Doing an `lshw` shows `DISABLED` written against my networks and `link=no` in each of them, whereas under normal circumstances (e.g. proper working internet on a live boot), the word `DISABLED` is absent and `link=yes`. Any ideas how we might resolve this?

```
$ lshw -C network

  *-network:0 DISABLED  <---------------------- Dongle
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.6.4
       logical name: enxfcde56ff0106
       serial: fc:de:56:ff:01:06
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=no multicast=yes
       
  *-network:1 DISABLED  <---------------------- Tethered phone
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1.5
       logical name: usb0
       serial: ea:af:19:e2:c4:6c
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=no multicast=yes
```

- also my network settings appear as such

[image]

Comment: Since your system cannot connect to Internet right now ... Probably [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393) will help you connect to Internet and fix the broken upgrade.

Comment: Thanks!! This was a great starting point, although it didn't help at first. I did an update+upgrade through live boot by mounting the appropriate folders as instructed in your link. Nothing changed. On further investigation of `systemctl`, I found that there was some problem with the `user@1000.service`

Comment: So I looked for the issue and the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290430/systemd-user-daemons-fail-to-start-after-after-update-removed-snap) partially worked. Again, to run this I needed to take the live-boot route, so that's what I did. And now the lag in system setttings is fixed.

Comment: Most of the output in your `systemctl --state=not-found` is usual ... I would suggest reinstalling ubuntu-desktop like so `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Hooray!!! It worked. You have been the real help mate. The mess with system menu and sound settings got resolved. Now, the only thing left is the internet. My system detects USB, and I can transfer files. But I guess it is unable to switch modes on  the dongle for internet connectivity. I have detailed my further investigations in UPDATE 2 above. Please see if you would be so nice to put a little more effort.

Comment: That is good news, please add your Ubuntu version to your question ... Boot to the live system and connect to internet first then chroot to the system on the hard disk and Purge `sudo apt remove --purge usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data` then install it again with `sudo apt install usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data` ... see if this fixes your dongle issue.

Comment: You were one of the luckier posters in this situation. Usually Ubuntu doesn't boot after interrupted upgrade.

Comment: @Raffa 
This is the second time I was put on a false scent. Turned out that that usb-modeswitch 'failed' problem is there even in the live boot version of Ubuntu. But I think it isn't the actual problem at all, beacuse despite that error in live boot, my dongle and mobile tethering work flawlessly there. Sry again for making something usual look like a problem. Should've checked beforehand. However, I still tried the purge and reinstall of modeswitch: no success.

Comment: @NateT Yeah, I'm thankful for that. Just trying my best to evade an OS reinstall.

Comment: @Raffa Please see update 3 above. It may take us closer to our networking problem. Looking forward to your help 

Answer (score 1):

1. Never, ever do that. Now you know why.
2. Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`
3. If that doesn't fix your problem, then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I guess the update broke a lot of things. However, I was able to get into my system through live boot and do the steps you mentioned. There was no other way since the internet is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. I looked at what packages were installed before the icons disappeared:

```
$ grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
2021-07-06 11:53:52 install libsystemd0:i386 <none> 245.4-4ubuntu3.7
2021-07-06 11:53:53 install libudev1:i386 <none> 245.4-4ubuntu3.7
2021-07-06 11:53:53 install libapparmor1:i386 <none> 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libcap2:i386 <none> 1:2.32-1
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libargon2-1:i386 <none> 0~20171227-0.2
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 <none> 2:1.02.167-1ubuntu1
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libjson-c4:i386 <none> 0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libssl1.1:i386 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.4
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libcryptsetup12:i386 <none> 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libgmp10:i386 <none> 2:6.2.0+dfsg-4
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libnettle7:i386 <none> 3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libhogweed5:i386 <none> 3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2
2021-07-06 11:53:54 install libffi7:i386 <none> 3.3-4
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install libp11-kit0:i386 <none> 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install libtasn1-6:i386 <none> 4.16.0-2
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install libgnutls30:i386 <none> 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.3
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install libip4tc2:i386 <none> 1.8.4-3ubuntu2
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install libkmod2:i386 <none> 27-1ubuntu2
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install libseccomp2:i386 <none> 2.5.1-1ubuntu1~20.04.1
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install systemd-timesyncd:i386 245.4-4ubuntu3.6 245.4-4ubuntu3.7
2021-07-06 11:53:55 install systemd:i386 245.4-4ubuntu3.6 245.4-4ubuntu3.7
2021-07-06 11:57:34 install distro-info:amd64 <none> 0.23ubuntu1
```

2. Reinstalled all:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall distro-info systemd systemd-timesyncd libseccomp2 libkmod2 libip4tc2 libgnutls30 libtasn1-6 libp11-kit0 libffi7 libhogweed5 libnettle7 libgmp10 libcryptsetup12 libssl1.1 libjson-c4 libdevmapper1.02.1 libargon2-1 libcap2 libapparmor1 libudev1 libsystemd0
```

3. Rebooted